# Sqlite Proximity Search

Tags: sqlite, proximity

I have a text stored in my Sqlite table like:

`stackoverflow`

Is it possible to select this word with something like:
`SELECT * FROM record WHERE name (looks_close_to) 'stockoverflaw'`?

I don't know how to put this clearly, proximity search I guess?

PS: I'm trying to give my user the correct word `'stackoverflow'` when they typed `'stockoverflaw'` insteed.

Comment: Stuff like this is what the spellfix1 extension module was made for. Populate a spellfix virtual table with your known good words, look up user-supplied ones in it, take the first match and see if that's in your real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Shawn for the comment.
The **[Spellfix1](https://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html)** extension is what I was looking for.

> This spellfix1 virtual table can be used to search a large vocabulary for close matches. For example, spellfix1 can be used to suggest corrections to misspelled words. Or, it could be used with FTS4 to do full-text search using potentially misspelled words.